usb4java GraalVM native compatibility issues
We have a SpringBoot3 app that communicates with virtual UART port via USB. App runs just fine as a JAR, however, there are strange issues we face once it gets compiled to a native .exe using GraalVM. Some methods of usb4java work fine, some work only partially and one method even causes a segfault.
For example,
Context context = new Context();
int result = LibUsb.init(context);

will result in

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null not supported as key!

while calling it as
LibUsb.init(null);

will work just fine,
list = new DeviceList();
result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(context, list);

works alright, as well as
Version version = LibUsb.getVersion();  

however, calling
descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
result = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, descriptor);

causes segfault right away.
Once again, none of this happens given app is run as jar.
Was able to find very little info on that issue on the Internets.

Looks like have it sorted.
All these glitches happen because of missing method fields in jni-config.json,
once
{
  "name":"org.usb4java.Context",
  "fields":[{"name":"contextPointer"}]
},
{
  "name":"org.usb4java.Device",
  "fields":[{"name":"devicePointer"}],
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.usb4java.DeviceDescriptor",
  "fields":[{"name":"deviceDescriptorBuffer"}, {"name":"deviceDescriptorPointer"}]
},
{
  "name":"org.usb4java.DeviceList",
  "fields":[{"name":"deviceListPointer"}, {"name":"size"}]
},

added, the problem's gone.
